# Hermite polynomial

Tags: polynomials, hermite-polynomials

\begin{equation}h''(x) - 2xh'(x) = -2 \lambda h(x), x \in R  \end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue.

\begin{equation} G(t,x) = \sum_{n=0}^ {\infty} t^nh_n = e^{2tx-t^2} \end{equation}

This means that by expanding $G(t, x)$ into Taylor series in t, one can recover $h_n(x)$. Now compute
$h_0, h_1, h_2, h_3$ and plug the expression you get into the first equation and obtain the corresponding eigenvalue.

I've done this and I'm getting:

$h_0 = 1$

$h_1 = 2x$

$h_2 = 4x^2-2$

$h_3 = 8x^3-12x$

And when I'm putting this back in the first equation I get:

$\lambda_0 = 0$

$\lambda_1 = 1$

$\lambda_2 = 2$

$\lambda_3 = 3$

Is this correct?

Comment: This is more suited to math.stackexchange

Comment: Close, but not quite. You are not expanding the Taylor series of $G$ properly, so you are getting multiples of the correct $h_n$. However, a multiple of an eigenfunction of the equation is also an eigenfunction for the same eigenvalue, so you are getting the correct eigenvalues.